# Can I patent a communication protocol?

Tags: patentability, legal

Is it possible to patent a communication protocol, like HTTP or IMAP or SMTP, etc..?

How about a sequence of REST APIs?

If not, is there anyway to prevent others developing clone applications that will be compatible with my application?

If yes, any pointers to a similar patent would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last year the answer for protocols was yes. It might still be yes at the USPTO but now it is likely for a judge with no technical background to say "it is just doing what computers do". APIs have not been found patentable but they are copyrightable - unless the case that Google wants to take to the Supreme Court goes the other way. Some links. [PatentlyO on Google vs Oracle/Sun](http://patentlyo.com/patent/2014/11/copyrighting-software-oracle.html), [PatentlyO on are API's patentable or copyrightable](http://patentlyo.com/patent/2014/05/copyright-subject-matter.html).